# How to insert value of input text value when radio button is checked in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I creating a short question form and I want to insert the value of input text when the radio button is checked. Currently I can only insert the value of radio button but not the value of my input text.
How can I do this ?

HTML code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assets/index_style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Assets/jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        //back button function
        function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <div class="container">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href='admin_home.php'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Back to home
        </button><br>

        <h3 class="text-muted">Short Question Form</h3>

        <form action="admin_shortquestform.php" method="post">

            <table class="table">

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Question:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="70" name="questiontext"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1. </td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="60" name="ans1"><input type="radio" name="radioans" value="1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2. </td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="60" name="ans2"><input type="radio" name="radioans" value="2" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3. </td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="60" name="ans3"><input type="radio" name="radioans" value="3" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4. </td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="60" name="ans4"><input type="radio" name="radioans" value="4" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table></form>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2016 FYP, Inc.</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:-

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'dbConn.php';

if(!empty($_POST{'submit'})) {


    $questiontext = $_POST['questiontext'];
    $anstext1 = $_POST['ans1'];
    $anstext2 = $_POST['ans2'];
    $anstext3 = $_POST['ans3'];
    $anstext4 = $_POST['ans4'];


    if(empty($questiontext) && empty($anstext1) && empty($anstext2) && empty($anstext3) && empty($anstext4)) {
        echo "Please enter data";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'admin_mcqform.php';\",2000);</script>";
        return false;

    }
    if(!isset($_POST['radioans']))
    {
        echo "Please enter data";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'admin_mcqform.php';\",2000);</script>";
        return false;
    }

    $radiobtn = $_POST['radioans'];
    try {


        //add the first record into question table
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `question`(question_text, question_type) VALUES(:questiontext, 'shortquestion')");
        $stmt1->bindParam(":questiontext",$questiontext);
        $stmt1->execute();

        //add the last id insert for question into option tbl question_id
        $questionID = $conn->lastInsertId();
        $answerID = $conn->lastInsertId();

        //add second record into option_tbl
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer,question_id) VALUES(:ans,$questionID)");

        $stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$anstext1);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$anstext2);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$anstext3);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$anstext4);
        $stmt2->execute();

        //add third record into answer table
        $stmt3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `answer`(answer_text,question_id) VALUES(:radioans,$answerID)");
        $stmt3->bindParam(":radioans",$radiobtn);
        $stmt3->execute();

        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        exit;

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Why did you tag phpstrorm here?

Comment: i'm using phpstorm.

Comment: you only execute `INSERT INTO 'option_tbl'...` once. Did you mean to execute it 4 times (once for each answer text)? You bind the parameter 4 times, but each time you just overwrite the previous binding. I think maybe you need to execute the statement after each bind command, then re-bind and execute again until you've inserted all 4 records. Unless I have misunderstood the intention

Comment: my intention is to execute the answer if the user check the radio buttton.

Comment: so the user can type into 4 text boxes, but you only want to save the one next to the selected radio button? What is the point of 4 text boxes then? Why is the user allowed to type in 4 if you don't save it? Surely only 1 text box would be better?

Comment: i can save the input of 4 text boxes but in addition to that i want to save the answer which user check the radio button beside it.

Comment: I don't understand. The 4 textboxes _are_ the answer which the user checks. Currently you are _not_ saving the four textboxes. You only save the last one, as I already explained. And you already _are_ saving the radio button value. If you want to detect which of the textboxes matches the radio button, it's easy. `$radioBtn` will be 1, 2, 3, or 4, and your textboxes are ans1, 2, 3, or 4. So just do `$stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$_POST["ans" + $radioBtn]);` But I repeat, why can the user type into 4 boxes but only 1 is saved? I think the user will be confused.

Comment: in the stmt 2 saves the input of user and it will stored all the 4 answer on second table. But now i want to know which answer does the user checked on the radio button and save on the third table.

Comment: are you not reading what I say? Currently you are **not** saving the four textboxes. Only the last one is saved. I showed you how to change things to fix this. Also "But now i want to know which answer does the user checked on the radio button and save on the third table" - you are already doing this!! Unless it is not working for some reason, in which case you need to explain what is happening instead.

Answer (score 0):

**It can be Achieved by using a little bit of java script . or you can use
J query (lines of codes will be less) . Iam using java script here...**

```
    <!-- The id of input type=text  and Value of radio must be the same for each items/rows-->

  <form id="myForm" action="admin_shortquestform.php" method="POST">

    1.<input type="text" size="20" name="ans2" id="1"><input type="radio" name="radioans" value="1"/><br>
    2.<input type="text" size="20" name="ans3" id="2"><input type="radio" name="radioans" value="2" /><br>
    3.<input type="text" size="20" name="ans4" id= "3" ><input type="radio" name="radioans" value="3" /><br>



      <!-- selected ans is set to the below hidden input field in js function, and you can get it in php by using $_POST['selected_ans'] -->

      <input type="hidden" name="selected_ans" id="hidden_input" />


      <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()"  value="Submit">

    </form>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {

       var radios = document.getElementsByName('radioans');

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {


            var selected_radio_value=radios[i].value;

            var selected_text_input=document.getElementById(selected_radio_value);

            var selected_text_input_value=selected_text_input.value;//selected textbox value

            var input_hidden=document.getElementById("hidden_input");

            input_hidden.value=selected_text_input_value+"";// setting selected textbox value to hidden input field




             document.getElementById("myForm").submit();// submitting the form


            break;
        }


    }
    }
    </script>
```

**And in your form action php file (admin_shortquestform.php):-**

1. use 
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') instead of   if(!empty($_POST{'submit'}))
2. you can get the selected ans by writing the below code

   $selected_answer=$_POST['selected_ans'];

Comment: Is there any ans1 for the name field ?

Comment: I get this error when i submitting. SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'question_type' at row 1

Comment: the no.of characters specified for database column 'question_type' is less than the no.of characters passed to the table.

In phpmyadmin ,go to to the structure of the table and put some higher value to the length field of that column